# How to insert rows in a table depending on a different table?

Tags: sql, database, case, sql-insert

I have two tables.
One `user` table containing the user_id, user_email, user_name 
and other `user_status` table containing user_email, status. 
The issue I am facing is the `user_status` table is newly added and it is empty. The `user` table is already in the production. I want to achieve a scenario where I can add the rows in the `status` table without cleaning the db.

If the `user_name` is empty, then the `status` in the `user_status` table would be `offline` otherwise `online`.

```
user_id    user_email    user_name   
1          xyz@gmail.com   xyz       
2          abc@gmail.com
```

If this is my `user` table and my `user_status` table is empty, then I want to update the `user_status` table as:

```
user_email         status    
xyz@gmail.com      active    
abc@gmail.com      inactive
```

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server <> Oracle <> Postgres. Please don't spam the database tags, only tag the one database you are using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `insert ...select` and a conditional expression:

```
insert into user_status(user_email, status)
select user_email, case when user_name is null then 'offline' else 'online' end
from users
```

This assumes that by "empty" you mean `null`. If you really mean *empty string*, then the condition in the `case` should be `where user_name = ''` instead.

Note that `user` is a language keyword in almost all databases, hence not a good choice for a column name. I renamed it to `users` in the query.

Comment: Yes, most databases have user as reserved keyword, but for example MySQL doesn't. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_reserved_words.

Comment: @jarlh: inMySQL it is not a reserved word but it is [a keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-U) - so still not a very good choice for a table name.

Comment: thanks for the answer. actually it was just an example so I used `user`